# How to ask a time interval elapsed since a certain point time?

Tags: questions

Consider there are 100 bacteria at 12:00. Each bacterium divides into 2 every 10 minutes, for example.
The process of dividing into 2 is called binary fission.

- The first binary fission occurs **10 minutes** after 11:00.
- The second binary fission occurs **20 minutes** after 11:00.

## Question

How to ask the bold words? My attempt is as follows, but I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

> Find the elapsed time since 11:00 at which the n-th binary fission occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many minutes after 11:00 does the n-th binary fission occur?

The use of "n-th" means that the context must be a maths test. So if you can use mathematical notation you can be less ambiguous but more wordy:

> Let *t*(*n*) be the time in minutes after 11:00 at which the *n*-th binary fission occurs.
>
> Find an expression for *t*(*n*) in terms of *n*.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:

**If binary fission (of the bacteria) first occurs at 11.10 and repeats every ten minutes, determine the elapsed time before the nth division.**

Comment: The elapsed time before the first division is zero?

Comment: Hmmm! How about? **If the binary division (of x bacteria) begins at 11.00 and repeats every 10 minutes, determine the elapsed time before the nth division.** (However, this overlooks the 100 bacteria at 12.00, which would be impossible if the bacteria concerned had begun splitting at 11.00. Did you mean 100 at 11.00?)